# Form header and footer appearing with a wrong color and font size for 1-2 seconds when shown inside a Sheet

Tags: swiftui

I am seeing `Form` behaving strange sometimes when it is in a sheet - section titles are shown initally larger and black and then change to the correct size & color after 1-2 seconds (also happening the other way round):

[image: Form glitch]

To reproduce, run this example snippet, press the 'Show sheet' button at least two times, you'll see the glitch when the sheet is shown for the second time (tested on iOS 16.2 and 16.3, happening both in Simulator and Device):

```swift
struct SheetView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(
                header: Text("Title"),
                footer: Text("Explanation"),
                content: {
                    Text("Example")
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Hello world")) {
                    HStack(spacing: 20) { // <<< removing this HStack fixes it
                        Button(
                            action: {
                                self.showSheet = true
                            },
                            label: {
                                Text("Show Sheet")
                            }
                        )
                        .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                            SheetView()
                        }

                        Button("Other Button") {}
                            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For some strange reason, removing the HStack in the outer view fixes it.

This seems like a bug in SwiftUI, I am posting this question to document it with the question being: Is this a SwiftUI bug? Any workarounds known if you need that HStack / any insights what's going on here?

Comment: Reported as FB12000290 to Apple.

Answer (score 2):

If you have lots of sheets to display, declare an `enum` to represent your sheets, use the `.sheet(item:)` modifier, and put it at the top level. This fixes your font problem:

```
enum Sheet: Identifiable {
    var id: Self { self }
    case sheet1
}

struct SheetView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(
                header: Text("Title"),
                footer: Text("Explanation"),
                content: {
                    Text("Example")
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var sheet: Sheet? = nil

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Hello world")) {
                    HStack(spacing: 20) {
                        Button(
                            action: {
                                self.sheet = .sheet1
                            },
                            label: {
                                Text("Show Sheet")
                            }
                        )
                        .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                        Button("Other Button") {}
                            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(item: $sheet) { sheet in
            switch sheet {
            case .sheet1:
                SheetView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That does not solve the issue for me. After triggering it a few times, the issue reappears.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the .sheet() being attached to the Button that triggers it; if this Button is in a layout container, this can affect the contents of the sheet like in the example above.

As a workaround, the .sheet() modifier can be moved up in the View hierarchy.

Comment: That does not solve the issue for me. After triggering it a few times, the issue reappears.